# How to access non fully constructed objects?

Tags: c#, constructor, action, instantiation

I have a class that takes an Action for the constructor, let's say class A.

```
public class A
{
    public A(Action action) {...}
}
```

and I instantiate it.

```
class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        A a = new A(() => { DoSomethingWith(x); });
    }
}
```

The question is: How can I refer to 'a' in my action? In other words, how can I replace 'x' with 'a'?
I tried 'this' keyword but it refers to Program.
By the way, I can not use other inputs for my constructor, because the actions are very random in this project.

Comment: You can't, because `a` isn't fully constructed when you create the Action delegate.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Please post a more complete example of what you are after

Comment: @RonBeyer that's what I was looking for. Please answer my question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` isn't fully constructed until the constructor runs. That means that it isn't available inside the `Action` delegate at that point. If you want, you can create a different type of Action delegate:

```
public class A
{
    public A(Action<A> myAction)
    {
        myAction(this);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        var myA = new A((a) => { DoSomethingWithA(a); });
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithA(A a)
    {

    }
}
```

That allows it to be called with itself as an argument. The straight `Action` won't work though because you can't capture `a` before it is fully constructed.

This does seem to be an X-Y problem though, and I would avoid doing this if possible because it is difficult to tell if `DoSomething` is using a fully initialized `A` before the action is called, which can leave your object in an undetermined state. There are uses, just be careful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a very nice solution. I don't see my question X-Y, what else should I be asking?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you can't assign the action in the constructor because `a` has not been constructed yet. Don't confuse *assigning* the action with *running* it. You probably want to run the action at a different time to when you create `a`.

Without necessarily condoning the approach (it's a bit ugly and there's probably a better way to achieve your ends), you could do something like this instead:

```
public class A
{
    Action<A> MyAction
    public A(Action<A> action) 
    {
        MyAction = action;
    }
    public void DoMyAction() 
    {
        MyAction(this);
    }
}

class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        var a = new A((x) => { DoSomethingWith(x); });
        a.DoMyAction();
    }
}
```